# Webhost database user access denied

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, web-hosting

My developer built the website and hosted it on godaddy. It was working find but then I decided to change the Database "user" password. (Hosting > Manage > Database (Mysql) > change password (all they at the bottom)"

After that when i try to access the site it gives me following error.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 161

Backtrace:

File: /home/baher/public_html/application/core/My_Controller.php
Line: 22
Function: __construct

File: /home/baher/public_html/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 24
Function: __construct

File: /home/baher/public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

I have changed it a couple of times, but still same error. Godaddy customer support also didnt know what was going on. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to change the pasword in the code to match

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the password in the file as well to match the changed password.

Comment: Which file should I be looking for?